# RenderUI with a conditional

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app with a conditional layout. The issue is, I am facing an obstacle in generating the layout I would prefer. From what I have read online its due to you not being able to output a `renderUI` with a conditional although I'm not entirely sure as even though the code seems to work the `conditionalPanel`s do not show at all.

The app will take a user input which in this case will allow the user to select from a list of variables. Based on the users selected variables I want to generate `n` number of widgets which allow you to define each of the variables with a probability distribution (normal, uniform, log normal, triangular etc). Once the user selects a distribution for `n1` depending on the distribution a set of conditional panels would become visible asking the user to select what ever argument is required in order to populate the variable (`n1` in this case) as depicted in the image below.

If anyone can come up with a workaround/solution would be great
This is the layout I am looking for when selecting each of the variables:
[image: Required layout]

**EDIT: Made some progress**

Updated code but conditional panels are all showing instead of those related to the PDF function selected only.

```
library(shiny)

ui= fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "invar", label= "invar", 
                     choices= names(iris), 
                     selected= names(iris)[1],
                     multiple=T),
      uiOutput("invarpd")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab")
    )
  ))


server= function(input, output,session) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[ ,c(input$invar)]
    #print(input$invar)
    data})

  output$invarpd <- renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar)
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
      tagList(
        selectInput(inputId=paste0("invarpd",input$invar[i]),paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                    choices = c("Normal","Uniform","Triangular")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inputId=='Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25),
                         textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inputId=='Uniform'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 0.3)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inputId=='Triangular'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value:", 0.3)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inputId=='Log Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmeanlog","Please Select Mean Log of Input Variable:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfsdlog","Please Select Standard Deviation Log of Input Variable:", 0.3)),
        textInput("label", "Label")
      )})})


  output$MonteCarlo <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(1)


    n <- input$sampleSize




    if(distinvarpdf=="Normal"){

      invarpdfVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmean),sd= as.numeric(input$invarpdfsd))
    }
    if(distinvarpdf=="Uniform"){

      invarpdfVec <- runif(n,min = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmin),max = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmax))
    }
    if(distinvarpdf=="Triangular"){

      invarpdfVec <- rltriangle(n,a = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmin),b = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmax))
    }
    if(distinvarpdf=="Log Normal"){

      invarpdfVec <- rlnorm(n,meanlog = as.numeric(input$invarpdfmeanlog),sdlog = as.numeric(input$invarpdfsdlog))
    }




    h<- hist(distinvarpdf,breaks=30,col="red",freq=F)
  })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT 2:**
Made some further progress. Now the first variable responds to the conditional but the subsequent selected variables do not

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
    wellPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "invar", label= "Select Variable", 
                     choices= names(iris), 
                     selected= names(iris)[1],
                     multiple=T),
  uiOutput("moreControls"))),


  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("tab")
  )
))
server <- function(input, output) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[ ,c(input$invar)]
    #print(input$invar)
    data})

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar)
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
    tagList(
      selectInput("inv",paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                  choices = c("Normal","Uniform","Triangular","Log Normal")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Normal'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25),
                       textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Uniform'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                       textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 0.3)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Triangular'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                       textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value:", 0.3)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Log Normal'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmeanlog","Please Select Mean Log of Input Variable:",0.18),
                       textInput("invarpdfsdlog","Please Select Standard Deviation Log of Input Variable:", 0.3))

    )})})
}





shinyApp(ui, server)
```